# How to perform PAM clustering in Python given a dissimilarity matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis

I have a dataframe df that has the columns id, text, lang, stemmed, and tfidfresult. df has 24 rows. I found the dissimilarity matrix (distance matrix) based on the tfidf result which gives how dissimilar two rows in the dataframe are.

A sample of how the dataframe looks is:

```
   id     text                lang                    stemmed                  tf_idfresult
0 234  Hi this                  en [hi, this]                   [0.0, 0.2]
1 232  elephants ruined again   en [elephants, ruined, again]   [0.1, 0.0, 0.0]
2 441  there are palm trees     en [there, are, palm, trees]    [0.2, 0.54, 0.0, 0.823]
3 235  so much to do            en [so, much, to, do]           [0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0]
```

The dissimilarity matrix dis was found with the help of the cosine_similarity function and looks as

```
[[0.0, 0.3, 0.1, 1, 1...]
[0.1, ...]
.
.
```

for 24 rows and 24 columns.

I used silhouette method and found the best value for k which is 3.  I tried doing

```
pam = kmedoids(dis, initialmedoids)
```

but I don't know how to find the initial medoids.
The expected output is the dataframe in three clusters. I don't have any specific format for the output.

Comment: Please provide a full copy and pastable sample pandas dataset as well as your expected output. Please see how to ask pandas questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: @DavidErickson Okay I will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

I've also been trying to work with k-medoids and have been so lost! I read about a handful of tools for doing it. Two of them are:

- [sklearn_extra.cluster.KMedoids](https://scikit-learn-extra.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/sklearn_extra.cluster.KMedoids.html#sklearn_extra.cluster.KMedoids). Set the kargs `method='pam'` and `metric='precomputed'`. After running the analysis, you can see to which cluster each sample was assigned with kmedoids.labels_. You can use [this tutorial](https://scikit-learn-extra.readthedocs.io/en/stable/auto_examples/plot_kmedoids.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-kmedoids-py) as a basis for writing a program that separates the samples according to clusters.
- [pyclustering.cluster.kmedoid](https://pyclustering.github.io/docs/0.9.0/html/d0/dd3/classpyclustering_1_1cluster_1_1kmedoids_1_1kmedoids.html#aaea9e022dc688acbb7bfff7c993fb84f). This is the one you're using, I guess? In accordance to your code, you should:

```
from pyclustering.cluster.kmedoids import kmedoids

pam = kmedoids(dis, initialmedoids)

pam.process()

clusters = pam.get_clusters()
```